# Normalmap texture in Unity from SP disorted a lot

Tags: unity, textures, uv-mapping, normal-mapping

As title said, normalmap made from Substance Painter in Unity disorted. Here is the picture:

[image]

I made red rectangles to see more cleary. You can see that the some of line of normal were disorted obviously.

I have no Idea why this happens. Model made from Blender 2.78c and exported as FBX. Used Substance Painter 2017.3.3 and tested in Unity 5.6.x and 2017/2018.1.f1.

Any advice will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Allegorithmic forum, Blender and Substance Painter handles 3d object differently.

Before export FBX from Blender, make sure triangulate object, and in my case it works.

Importing in Unity doesn't have to triangulated, and works perfect with texture painted from Substance Painter that triangulated.